# How to replace $-x^{}\,y^*-y^{}\,x^*$ by $-(x^{}\,y^*+y^{}\,x^*)$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, factorization

Up to now, I have tried some codes like the following:

```
(*Abs[Sh]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
 Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 - 
 Sv Conjugate[Sh] Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 - 
 Sh Conjugate[Sv] Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2*)

hvhv = hvhv /. {-x_ Conjugate[y_] (Cos[ϕ_])^2 (Sin[ϕ_])^2 - 
     y_ Conjugate[
       x_] (Cos[ϕ_])^2 (Sin[ϕ_])^2 -> -(x Conjugate[y] + 
        y Conjugate[x]) (Cos[ϕ])^2 (Sin[ϕ])^2}

(*Abs[Sh]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
 Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + (-Sv Conjugate[Sh] - 
    Sh Conjugate[Sv]) Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2*)

hvhv = hvhv /. {-x_ Conjugate[y_] - 
     y_ Conjugate[x_] -> -(x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])}

(*Abs[Sh]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
 Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + (-Sv Conjugate[Sh] - 
    Sh Conjugate[Sv]) Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2*)
```

But as you see none of them seems to work. In order to find the reason, I used the way of [The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/30689) and I found out that both of the expressions have the same internal form and so they can not be replaced by each other.

```
-(x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x]) // FullForm
(*Plus[Times[-1,y,Conjugate[x]],Times[-1,x,Conjugate[y]]]*)

-x Conjugate[y] - y Conjugate[x] // FullForm
(*Plus[Times[-1,y,Conjugate[x]],Times[-1,x,Conjugate[y]]]*)
```

Now there are two questions:

1. The internal form of `-(x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])` shoud be `(*Times[-1,Plus[Times[y,Conjugate[x]],Times[x,Conjugate[y]]]]*)` by why is it `(*Plus[Times[-1,y,Conjugate[x]],Times[-1,x,Conjugate[y]]]*)`?
2. Is there any way to replace $-x^{}\,y^*-y^{}\,x^*$ by $-(x^{}\,y^*+y^{}\,x^*)$?

Comment: The internal form is what you think it is, however in your last codeblock it is immediately evaluated: `HoldForm[-(x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])] // FullForm` gives `HoldForm[Times[-1, 
  Plus[Times[x, Conjugate[y]], Times[y, Conjugate[x]]]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This offers no proper explanation, but seems to work in your case. The replacement rule is

```
Abs[Sh]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 +
  (-Sv Conjugate[Sh] - Sh Conjugate[Sv]) Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 /.
{z_ (-x_ Conjugate[y_] - y_ Conjugate[x_]) :> -z (x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])}

(* Abs[Sh]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
   Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 - 
   (Sv Conjugate[Sh] + Sh Conjugate[Sv]) Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 *)
```

and puts the expression in the desired form. I guess, it's because

```
-(x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])
(* -y Conjugate[x] - x Conjugate[y] *)
```

whereas

```
-z (x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x])
(* -z (x Conjugate[y] + y Conjugate[x]) *)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to factorize all `Cos Sin`s. I can do that simply by the `collect` function but I don't want.